# How to manage a git repository in other git repository subfolder?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have following directories.

I am in situation that I co-work in main_dir with Alice and Bob.
But I want to manage only my Charles directory in other repository.

```
├─main_dir
│  ├─Alice
│  ├─Bob
│  └─Charles
```

My question is,
How can I co-work in main_dir (main repository) and I manage my works in individual repository at the same time.

I have 3 ideas.

1. git init in main_dir/Charles.

- After my work finished, I do 'git push main_repository master' in main_dir.
- And move to main_dir/Charles And do 'git push individual_repository master'
  But, I worry that it makes main repository too heavy.

2. Make new_Charles directory and move new_Charles git init. Then, copy-paste my works from main_dir/Charles to new_Charles.

- After my work finished, I do 'git push main_repository master' in main_dir.
- And copy-paste main_dir/Charles to new_Charles.
- And move to new_Charles, 'git push individual_repository master'
  But, It is too inefficient.

3. Manage 2 .gitignore files. The first one is for main_repository, other one is for individual repository. .gitignore file for individual repository ignores Alice and Bob directory.

- After my work finished, I do 'git push main_repository master' in main_dir.
- And switch .gitignore files. (.gitignore -> .main_gitignore & .indi_gitignore -> .gitignore)
- And 'git push individual_repository master'
- Finally, re-switch .gitignore files. (.gitignore -> .indi_gitignore & .main_gitignore -> .gitignore)
  But, The work of Changing gitignore files is recoreded in commit history.

Comment: What is the relationship between Alice, Bob, and Charles? Why have Charles in main_dir at all?

Comment: Alice, Bob, and Charles are the pseudonyms of developers who develop different features. Because of security, I use pseudonyms not features.

Comment: Why don't you just use "branch"?  Each of you can maintain your own branch, you can choose to merge or "cherry-pick" the changes in other branches to your own branch.

Comment: @권순규 Do they need to be in the same directory at all?

Comment: @권순규 Is `main_dir` the directory you're running production code from?

Answer (score 0):

I think what's going on here is you have three developers all working on the same project wanting to coordinate their efforts. I think you're also making the common mistake of mixing up development with deployment; that is `main_dir` is a production directory.

Rather than having separate repositories in subdirectories of the main repository and then copying changes around, use Git's branches and push/pull mechanisms. You'd also have a separate step to deploy changes. That's too much, and too basic, to describe here. Here's the essentials.

- There is a single central repository you all push and pull from.
- Each developer has their own repository ***outside the central one***.
- Each developer pushes to the central repository.
- Each developer pulls updates from the central repository.
- You deploy from the central repository.

For example, let's say the central repository is `/path/to/repo`. It is a [bare repository](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bare-repositories-in-git/), no files are checked out. No code is executed from `/path/to/repo`, deployment is a separate step.

Each developer in their own workspace (probably their home directory) would `git clone /path/to/repo`. They'd do their work in their repository. When it's ready they `git push`. When they want get updates from other developers they `git pull`.

When you want to deploy you'd have another clone which pulls from `/path/to/repo` into production. Note it is a bad idea to use Git for deployment, but it will work.

For more, read the [Git Branching chapter of Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell). Consider using a Git hosting service such as Github and [their collaboration tools](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests). And look into more sophisticated workflows such as [Feature Branches](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow).